# How to identify changed objects in Sandbox

Tags: sandbox, change-set

Hi: My team had completed ton of changes in the Dev Sandbox - new configurations, layout changes, triggers etc.

Now, how do I identify all those changes, so that I can bundle them and move those changes to another Sandbox for QA testing?

This is the first time we are needed to move the changed objects, since we installed the Sandbox. Is there are an automated approach/tool to identify all those changes?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

*Disclaimer: I work for Gearset*

You could try Gearset (https://gearset.com) - we're designed to solve exactly that problem. You can run comparisons between two orgs, pick what you want to deploy, and push them to your QA sandbox in just a few clicks. There's a completely free 30 day trial with no commitment up front, and you don't need to install any managed packages or anything like that, so you can try it out totally risk free.

Answer (score 1):

[Salesforce Org Compare](https://sforgcompare.herokuapp.com/) : This tool uses the Salesforce Tooling or Metadata API (user selection) to compare metadata between two Orgs. This is useful when planning deployments or building deployment packages, as well as seeing what configuration exists in Production to Sandbox or between Sandbox environments.

You can also look into app exchange for [Metadata Glimpser: Org to Org Metadata Viewer](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N3000000B5HSYEA3)